# How To Apply Laravel SoftDeletes on all Models at once?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, model-view-controller

Is there a way I can include `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;`
and `use SoftDeletes;` on all my `Models` without needing to edit each model?
I want some way to make my models import it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `abstract` Model, and put there `SoftDeletes` and inherit other models from this abstract model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

abstract class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

And for example `User` model will be:

```
namespace App\Models;

class User extends AbstractModel
{

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I have too many models so I can\t make each model inherit from the abstract model manually I wish if there is a way that can make me save time and energy like some sort of packages  and thank you in Advance